# Access ContentControl (Combobox) in footer of Word-document

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

I have a Word-document with a footer that contains a combobox, which I would like to access using VBA.

I've seen similar questions being asked, where the answer was 'just don't use contentcontrols in footers', but that's not really an answer, is it. ;) The reason the combobox needs to stay, is because users can also manually select one of the options if necessary.

I know that ContentControls in the main document can be accessed using `ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text`
However, I have not found how to access ContentControls in the footer.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Kind regards,
Jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access ContentControls in the footer in exactly the same way that you access anything else that is in the footer. You need to determine which section contains the footer and which of the three footers contains the ContentControl.

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ContentControls(1).Range.Text
```